# SQL dbo to Custom Schema migration steps

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, dbo

I need steps to change my default **[dbo]** schema to some custom schema say **[TEST]** in SQL Database. I figured out some of the steps and want to make sure is there any other objects or procedure i should be aware of while migrating the schema.

I need to change the schema name for all my tables, views, functions, store procedures from [dbo] to [TEST].

Is there any other Sql objects i should consider while performing this migration?

Comment: Take a quick glance at `sys.objects` by their different `type_desc`.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few potential areas to look at.
At lot will depend on what is in use in your DB.

Things to look for:

- Triggers
- User Defined Datatypes/Tables
- Synonyms /  Server Links
- Partition Functions / Schemas

Then you may have SSIS,SSRS and SSAS dependencies which you might also want to change...

Whether or not you need to change any of this will be dictated by the exact reason you are moving to a different schema.

If this is something that you plan to do on a regular basis - it might pay dividends to look at your MODEL DB - you might be able to get some quick wins by changing some options here. NB - I wouldn't try this on a Production server !!!

rgds

John